# access a nested list element from a vector of names specifying the path

Tags: r, list

Hullo,

If I've got a function

```
foo <- function(list, name)
```

where I would want

```
foo(list, c("a", "b", "c"))
```

to return

```
list[[a]][[b]][[c]]
```

and also fail gracefully if `list[[a]][[b]][[c]]` doesn't exist,

How do I accomplish this ideally in base R?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `pluck`

```
foo <- function(list, name) {
        purrr::pluck(list, !!! name)
}
```

-testing

```
> lst1 <- list(a = list(b = list(c = 1:2)), b = list(d = list(e = 1:5)))

> foo(lst1, c("a", "b", "c"))
[1] 1 2
```

---

Or simply in `base R`

```
foo <- function(list, name) {
     list[[name]]
}
>  foo(lst1, c("a", "b", "c"))
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: amazing, this is exactly what I needed. what's the "!!!" for?

Comment: @mitmonghi that was done to evaluate  to get the value in 'name'

Comment: @mitmonghi you can get more info about the splice operator with `?"!!!"`.  Updated the base R option

Comment: ya know what, I never knew the `[[` function actually just works exactly like what I wanted. I'd assumed it didn't work that way. Note that the base R solution doesn't work with a mix of numeric indexes and names, i.e. `foo(lst1, c(1, "b", "c")` doesnt work while `pluck` does

Comment: @mitmonghi that is true, because `c` converts it to a single type